# How to convert my code to simultaneous http request in PHP with cURL

Tags: php, curl

I want to convert following code to simultaneous http request using PHP and cURL

```
   $select_ids = $db->query("SELECT job_id, tids FROM sent_items");    
    if ($select_ids->num_rows) {
        while($row = $select_ids->fetch_object()) {
            $records[] = $row;            
        }
        $select_ids->free();
    }

    print_r($records);

    if(!count($records)) {
        echo 'No records';
    } else {
        foreach ($records as $r) {      
            $chandle = curl_init();    
            $url = "http://api.mvaayoo.com/apidlvr/APIDlvReport?user=USER ID:PASSWORD&tid=$r->tids&jobid=$r->job_id";    
            curl_setopt($chandle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    
            curl_setopt($chandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    
            $curl_result[] = curl_exec($chandle);
        }    
    }
```

> print_r($records); returns jobid and tid

See [Here](http://s29.postimg.org/bxsglpfuv/2333.png)

I give the job id and tid to the api url

```
$url = "http://api.mvaayoo.com/apidlvr/APIDlvReport?user=USER ID:PASSWORD&tid=$r->tids&jobid=$r->job_id";
```

**tid=$r->tids&jobid=$r->job_id**

> $curl_result[] returns

See [Here](http://s3.postimg.org/rcz9pcgxv/3333333.jpg)

My Problem is how to convert above code to simultaneous http request ????

The code article

[Simultaneuos HTTP requests in PHP with cURL](http://www.phpied.com/simultaneuos-http-requests-in-php-with-curl/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create array of URLs what you want to use with CURL and send them to `multiRequest` function. See GET example in article.

So it will end up creating CURL for each of these URLs and making requests. After requests it will return results into `$multi_curl_result` as `array`. Then you can use returned data.

```
<?php

// Add multiRequest function here from article

$select_ids = $db->query("SELECT job_id, tids FROM sent_items");
if ($select_ids->num_rows) {
    while($row = $select_ids->fetch_object()) {
        $records[] = $row;
    }
    $select_ids->free();
}

if(!count($records)) {
    echo 'No records';
} else {
    $curls = array();
    foreach ($records as $r) {
        $curls[] = "http://api.mvaayoo.com/apidlvr/APIDlvReport?user=USER ID:PASSWORD&tid=$r->tids&jobid=$r->job_id";
    }

    $multi_curl_result = multiRequest($curls);
}
```

You could add ID to CURL job. Then you can get data from results array by ID.

```
$curls[$r->job_id] = "http://api.mvaayoo.com/apidlvr/APIDlvReport?user=USER ID:PASSWORD&tid=$r->tids&jobid=$r->job_id";
```

Now you know which data belongs to which job. For example if `job_id` would be `10`, then this job's data is in `$multi_curl_result[10]`.

**Some comments on how multiRequest function works**

`multiRequest` function ([source](http://www.phpied.com/simultaneuos-http-requests-in-php-with-curl/)).

```
function multiRequest($data, $options = array()) {

  // array of curl handles
  $curly = array();
  // data to be returned
  $result = array();

  // multi handle
  // Allows the processing of multiple cURL handles asynchronously.
  $mh = curl_multi_init();

  // loop through $data and create curl handles
  // then add them to the multi-handle
  foreach ($data as $id => $d) {
    // Create new CURL handle and add it to array
    // $id makes it possible to detect which result belongs to which request
    $curly[$id] = curl_init();

    // If $data item is array, get URL from array, otherwise item should be URL (for GET requests)
    $url = (is_array($d) && !empty($d['url'])) ? $d['url'] : $d;

    // Set regular CURL options
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_URL,            $url);
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_HEADER,         0);
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // If $data item is array, then we could have POST data
    if (is_array($d)) {
      // If item has POST data
      if (!empty($d['post'])) {
        // Set POST data
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POST,       1);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $d['post']);
      }
    }

    // Set extra CURL options from array
    if (!empty($options)) {
      curl_setopt_array($curly[$id], $options);
    }

    // Add normal CURL handle to a CURL multi handle
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $curly[$id]);
  }

  // execute the handles
  // $running will have value, if CURL is still running
  // Every execute will change it, until all requests has been done
  $running = null;
  do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
  } while($running > 0);

  // Add request responses to array
  // Recognizable by $id
  foreach($curly as $id => $c) {
    // Return the content
    $result[$id] = curl_multi_getcontent($c);

    // Removes CURL handle ($c) from multi handle ($mh)
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $c);
  }

  // All done
  curl_multi_close($mh);

  return $result;
}
```

Comment: your solution not working...so please explain with multiRequest() function definition

Comment: How it's not working? Any errors? I have explained how it works.

Comment: Yes. What doubts you have?

Comment: I am very new to PHP cURL can you explain multiRequest() function line by line in your answer because this is very useful for me and other viewers

Answer (score 0):

it is simple change your foreach like:

```
$data = array();
foreach ($records as $r) {                       
    $data[] = "http://api.mvaayoo.com/apidlvr/APIDlvReport?user=USER ID:PASSWORD&tid=$r->tids&jobid=$r->job_id";                  
}  

$curl_result = multiRequest($data);
```

Comment: I don't know full functionality of multiRequest($data); function, so please explain with multiRequest($data) function

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP's [curl_multi_init](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php%20curl_multi_init) but one of the many available libraries might make this easier than coding it all yourself.

Check these out:

> PHP-multi-curl: https://github.com/jmathai/php-multi-curl

and

> Guzzle: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle